# Matching a bone in one armature to a bone in another armature

Tags: armature

I have two armatures in my scene with identical structure (same number of bones, same bone names). I am trying to transform  each of the bones in skeleton b to match skeleton a. I want to end up with a two frame animation on skeleton b in which the first frame is all of the bones keyed at their rest position and the second frame all of the bones transformed to match skeleton a.

This is one approach I tried. I also tried simply setting the matrix of one to the matrix of the other.

```
import bpy

SOURCE_ARMATURE_NAME = 'Armature.001'
DEST_ARMATURE_NAME = 'Armature'

source_armature = bpy.data.objects[SOURCE_ARMATURE_NAME]
dest_armature = bpy.data.objects[DEST_ARMATURE_NAME]

bones_source = source_armature.pose.bones
bones_dest = dest_armature.pose.bones

bone_dict_source = {bone.name: bone for bone in bones_source}
bone_dict_dest = {bone.name: bone for bone in bones_dest}

matched_bones = []
for bone_name in bone_dict_source.keys():
    matched_bones.append((bone_dict_source[bone_name], bone_dict_dest[bone_name]))

for matched_pair in matched_bones:
    source_bone, dest_bone = matched_pair

    source_loc, source_rot_quat, source_scale = source_bone.matrix.decompose()
    target_loc, target_rot_quat, target_scale = dest_bone.matrix.decompose()

    loc_diff = target_loc - source_loc
    dest_bone.location += loc_diff

    rot_diff = target_rot_quat - source_rot_quat
    dest_bone.rotation_quaternion = rot_diff

    scale_diff = target_scale - source_scale
    dest_bone.scale += scale_diff
```

What am I doing wrong? This feels like it shouldn't be that difficult.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you try this approach what goes wrong?

Comment: Here's a before and after pair of images. The bones all move, but not at all to where I want them to

[url=https://postimg.cc/LhDRCQWN][img]https://i.postimg.cc/LhDRCQWN/before.png[/img][/url]

[url=https://postimg.cc/qg44GH1N][img]https://i.postimg.cc/qg44GH1N/AFTER.png[/img][/url]

Comment: Your code is fine as far as it goes, but you can't pose an armature that way.  You have to traverse bone chains from parent (root) to farthest child (tip) setting the position of each bone relative to its parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! It ended up being much simpler than I would have guessed. I was able to simply assign the matrix of the source bone to the destination bone. I had tried that before, but the key was traversing  the skeleton from root to tip as Marty Fouts pointed out in a comment, combined with a command to update the view layer. Without the update command, it uses the bone's matrix before the start of script execution.

```
import bpy

SOURCE_ARMATURE_NAME = 'Armature.001'
DEST_ARMATURE_NAME = 'Armature'

source_armature = bpy.data.objects[SOURCE_ARMATURE_NAME]
dest_armature = bpy.data.objects[DEST_ARMATURE_NAME]

bones_source = source_armature.pose.bones
bones_dest = dest_armature.pose.bones

bone_dict_source = {bone.name: bone for bone in bones_source}
bone_dict_dest = {bone.name: bone for bone in bones_dest}

bones_queue = []
bones_queue.append(bones_source[0].name)

for bone_name in bones_queue:
    source_bone = bones_source[bone_name]
    dest_bone = bones_dest[bone_name]

    dest_bone.matrix = source_bone.matrix

    for child_bone in source_bone.children:
        if child_bone.name not in bones_queue:
            bones_queue.append(child_bone.name)

    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```